# What does do double vertical bars with numerical parameters on the right hand side mean?

Tags: notation

In the following equation, $$\large R(Y) = \lambda \left\| \frac {x^\top Y} {\|x\|} \right\|^2_2$$ What do the double bars with range $2$ to $2$ on the right hand side mean? I need to work with this equation, but I don't understand what it is doing. Note, $x$ and $Y$ are both matrices, and $\lambda$ is just a constant.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Don’t forget to accept the post below if you feel it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the notation
$$\left\|x\right\|_\color{blue}{2}^\color{red}{2}$$

- the top (red) $\color{red}{2}$ simply means squaring, as in $x^2$;
- the bottom (blue) $\color{blue}{2}$ refers to the fact that it's the "2-norm", the standard [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) for the more general $p$-norm, of which this is a special case:
$$\left\| x \right\| _p = \left( |x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \dotsb + |x_n|^p \right) ^{1/p}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so lost as to what that was supposed to mean!